# Facebook app advertising doesn't report the AVG. COST PER MOBILE APP INSTALL

Tags: facebook

We have a mobile app (both iOS and Android) and we are promoting them on Facebook, using the "App installs" feature.

Both apps have been developed with the Facebook SDK integrated, so the Insights features work fine. Tracking of when the latest app install has been made, daily users, monthly active users, all these report data, they  work.

However, in the Facebook Ads Manager, particularly the campaign ads for app installs, I cannot see the Cost per Install. Any idea why is that?

Possible hint: can this be because, until today, the ads for app install were the old format? I mean NOT the format with social context features, that Facebook released in July, this year.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that you are advertising the "Dummy Facebook App" in the Mobile App install segment!

Don't use it's URL
Than you will receive mobile app install